# Convert base64'd SHA1 hashes to Hex hashes

Tags: php, hash

I have a list of passwords in mySQL that are generated using

```
$hash = '{SHA}' . base64_encode(sha1('some string here', true));
```

I need to convert these into what would be the equivalent of

```
$hash = sha1('some string here');
```

As these are password that our mail system uses, and we want to convert to another mail system (but requires that it be the 40 char hex hash :(

How would I convert from one format to the other (I'm pretty sure I've done this before, but the other way, though I can't find the code!)

As a note, I mentioned that the data is in mySQL - this is irrelevant - I know how to get the data, just not to convert it.

The hash is the same - I am only trying to convert the way the information is packed (I think this just needs to be converted from base64 to base16, but that's just a guess!)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$binary = base64_decode(substr($hash, 5));
$hex = bin2hex($binary);
```

Answer (score -3):

Well `base64_decode()` can be found in the base64_encode manual entry.
And I am sure they have a way to convert raw format in the sha1 manual entry comments, if it's too hard for you to write it yourself

Comment: I'm not converting hashes, just the way the hashes are packed.